# Редактирование класса

Tags: c#

В программе есть класс. В нём имеются следующие строки:

```
if (readingProfileHeader)
{
    // читаем строку вида
    // 1 1 1 58   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 114.497520   0.000000   0.000000 2   0.000000   0.000000

    pointCount = Convert.ToInt32(parts[3]);

    Xo = double.Parse(parts[4], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) * 1000;
    Xk = double.Parse(parts[7], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) * 1000;

    readingProfileHeader = false;
    readingProfileNumber = true;
    continue;
}
```

Далее ниже расчёты. Есть одно НО. Мы в обязательном порядке умножаем на 1000, но бывают случаи, когда этого делать не надо. Программно это не посмотреть, только пользователь может. 
Хочу использовать checkbox, чтобы если галочка стоит, то переводить, если нет, то не надо. Но в классе то не сошлёшься на checkbox.
Прошу не ругать, если сказал глупость. Учусь. Идей нет, как можно подредактировать класс.

Comment: Выставляйте свойство или параметр в методе. В чем проблема?

Comment: Да вот не знаю, как в классе это сделать. Меня хватает пока на bool b = checkBox1.Checked;
if (b == true){//...} else

Comment: Ну я же вам написал как: сделайте свойство в классе или параметр в методе.

Comment: Покажите как вы используете этот класс

Comment: Может так удобнее посмотреть будет, полная картина видна будет https://hdd.tomsk.ru/desk/jssiinqg# (там файл с классом и с вызовом.)

Comment: Ну передайте в метод `process` еще один параметр

Comment: Сейчас попробую сделать